# OrmLite - How get count of deleted rows?

Tags: android, ormlite

Android application using ORMlite with SQLite.  Here my method that delete some rows from table:

```
private static boolean apply(Dao<NotificationInvoice, Integer> invoiceDao) {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    try {
        String sql ="DELETE from notification where ownerkey not in ("123","456")";
        GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = invoiceDao.queryRaw(sql);
        isSuccess = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

It works. Successfully deletes N records from table. Nice.
The question is: How I can get count of deleted rows without doing a second query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DeleteBuilder` of *OrmLite*.

```
DeleteBuilder deleteBuilder = invoiceDao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where().notIn("ownerkey", new String[]{"123", "457"});
deleteCount = deleteBuilder.delete()
```